# ASP.NET 4.0 webforms routing within master page

Tags: routes, master-pages, url-routing, webforms-routing

I just want to asked if there's a workaround in url routing using masterpage. I put the links in my masterpage (i.e. first link is a href="Bookstore/CSS" and the other link is a href="tools/toolx") if i click the first link it redirect me to the correct url which is localhost:2039/Bookstore/but if i click the next link it will redirect me to localhost:2039/tools/Bookstore/CSS but the link should be localhost:2039/Bookstore/CSS.

Here is the code

global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute",
        "BookStore/{Name}",
        "~/Webpages/BookStore/ViewBookDemo.aspx");

        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("mytool",
        "tools/{Name}",
        "~/tools/tools.aspx");
    }
```

masterpage source code

```
<div class="page">
    <div >
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                URL Routing in MAsterpage
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="clear"> </div>
   <div style=" width:90%">
  <div style="float:left; width:25%;border: 1px solid #009933;"> 
  <br />
    <a href="Bookstore/CSS">Click Here to go to bookstore</a>.
   <div class="clear"> </div>
   <p>
      <a href="tools/toolx">Click Here to go to tools</a>.
  </p> </div>
   <div style="float:right;width:73%">
   <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
     <div class="clear"> </div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Menu Item click event try to get the item which is clicked and then use response.RedirectToRoute method. It requests to a new URL by using route name which you have specified in global.asax page . The sample code is :-

```
protected void NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)

    {
        MenuItem item = e.Item;
        if (item.Text == "Categories")
        {
            Response.RedirectToRoute("View Category");
        }
    }
```

The url routing  for "**View Category**" mentioned in global page is

```
  public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection route)
    {
        route.MapPageRoute("View Category", "Categories/All", "~/Views/Categories.aspx");
    }


   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }
```